# Typescript 1.0 with VS2013 Update 2 CTP: lots of breaking changes in our code

Tags: javascript, typescript

Today tried updating VS2013 to the Update 2 CTP release. All works fine but the TypeScript compiler has become too strict with our code. All code that was written with the 0.9.1.1 version is broken after the Update.

We have for instance code that extends the Kendo DataSource. In the DataSource a 'transport' property is present that has a 'parameterMap' property that accepts a function that is defined as follows:

```
interface DataSourceTransport {
    parameterMap?(data: DataSourceTransportParameterMapData, type: string): any;
}

interface DataSourceTransportParameterMapData {
    aggregate?: DataSourceParameterMapDataAggregate[];
    group?: DataSourceParameterMapDataGroup[];
    filter?: DataSourceParameterMapDataFilter;
    models?: Model[];
    page?: number;
    pageSize?: number;
    skip?: number;
    sort?: DataSourceParameterMapDataSort[];
    take?: number;
}
```

As you can see the parameterMap parameter accepts a function accepting a 'DataSourceTransportParameterMapData'.

Now in our code we extend this parameter with some extra properties like so:

```
parameterMap: function (data: any, operation: string) {
if (operation === "create") {
    data.TypeName = 'ActiviteitEntity';
}

if (operation === "update" || operation === 'destroy') {
    data.Xml = contractors.htmlEncode(data.Xml);
}               }
```

This construct was excepted fine by the 0.9.1.1 compiler but the 1.0 compiler tells me there is not 'TypeName' and 'Xml' property on the 'DataSourceTransportParameterMapData' which is correct. But we defined the 'data' parameter as an 'any' type.

So although we defined it as 'any' the compiler still refuses to add the new property (which b.t.w. would work fine in JavaScript).

This is just one of the problems I'm facing now but there are lots more which I haven't even started analizing yet.

I've uninstalled the Update 2 CTP for the moment but there will come a time that will have to switch to TypeScript 1.0. As I now estimate there is not a single piece of code that is not affected by the 1.0 version which is catastrophic.

Comment: Can you post a self-contained example that reproduces the problem described above?

Comment: I don't see any error in the Playground with a slightly trimmed-down version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I can bet the following code is not giving you any errors:

```
function parameterMap(data: any, operation: string) {
    if (operation === "create") {
        data.TypeName = 'ActiviteitEntity';
    }

    if (operation === "update" || operation === 'destroy') {
        data.Xml = contractors.htmlEncode(data.Xml);
    }               
}
```

But you *will* get errors if you try to do (sample 'a'):

```
var data:DataSourceTransportParameterMapData; 
parameterMap(data,'create'); 
console.log(data.TypeName); // Error TypeName does not exist on DataSourceTransportParameterMapData
```

Just because you pass a variable into a function (that accepts `any`) doesn't change the external type of a variable.

To tell typescript about your extensions to a type you can always do:

```
interface DataSourceTransportParameterMapData { 
    TypeName?: string;
}
```

And since interfaces are open ended (multiple definitions are merged), this would cause something like sample 'a' to compile as well.